# Attempting to paste an image onto another image

Tags: python, image

My goal in a school project is to be able to paste a logo onto various images for another company. However, my code seems to be bugged, and the image that is saved seems to be just a green rectangle. The color and width of said rectangle can change based on the string value and border variable 
on line 37. Could someone please be able to help me? Thank you!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
os.chdir('U:\Comp. Science\Lesson 1\Chapter 1.4\Project\Source Files\image7\Logo')
# imports modules and sets the working directory
SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 300
LOGO_FILENAME = 'logo.jpg'
logoIm = Image.open(LOGO_FILENAME)
logoWidth, logoHeight = logoIm.size
basewidth = 300
# Sets the image information for the logo
os.chdir('U:\Comp. Science\Lesson 1\Chapter 1.4\Project\Source Files\image7')
    # Loop over all files in the working directory.
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    print filename
    if not (filename.endswith('.png') or filename.endswith('.jpg')) \
        or filename == LOGO_FILENAME:
         continue # skip non-image files and the logo file itself
    im = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = im.size
    #sets image to open all filenames, also sets width and height to equal image size
# Check if image needs to be resized.
    if width > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE and height > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE:
        # Calculate the new width and height to resize to.
        if width > height:
            height = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / width) * height)
            width = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
        else:
            width = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / height) * width)
            height = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
    print('Resizing %s...' % (filename))
    im = im.resize((width, height))
    # Resizes the image and sets it to im
    print('Adding logo to %s...' % (filename))
    im.paste(logoIm, (width - logoWidth, height - logoHeight))
    background = ImageOps.expand(im,border=20,fill='green')
    background.save(os.path.join('WithLogo', filename))
    #adds the logo to the filename and then adds a background. and saves it
```

Comment: What if you skip adding the border?  Do the images look okay?  If yes then your error is on the border step.  If no, then the problem happens earlier on.

Comment: I know it happens earlier on because the dimensions are warped. If I removed the border it would just be either white nothing or a squished image.